# What is the best way to model a "superclass method implementation" in Go?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, interface, go

I am looking to translate a "classic OO" example into Go, one in which a set of subclasses implement some methods on their own but they share an implementation of some methods via their superclass.  I'm well aware of how to use Go's interfaces and I've even used embedding, but I'm not quite sure what, if any, idioms to employ to capture this intended behavior.

Here's a concrete, and probably a very familiar example.  I'll use Ruby.  There are two kinds of animals, dogs and cows.  All animals have a name and they can speak.  The way you set and get the same is the same regardless of the animal type; the sound they make differs depending on the subclass.  Now there is a `speak` method which is the same for all animals, but it delegates to the subclass's `sound` method.  Here it is in Ruby:

```
class Animal
  def initialize(name); @name = name; end
  def speak; puts "#{@name} says #{sound()}"; end
end
class Dog < Animal; def sound(); "woof"; end; end
class Cow < Animal; def sound(); "mooo"; end; end
```

How is this best captured in Go?

So far I've tried

```
type Animal struct {
    name string
}

type Cow struct {
    Animal
}

type Dog struct {
    Animal
}
```

and I've been able to construct "animals" like so:

```
func (d Dog) sound() string {return "woof"}
func (c Cow) sound() string {return "mooo"}

func main() {
    d := Dog{Animal{"Sparky"}}
    c := Cow{Animal{"Bessie"}}
    fmt.Println(d.name)
    fmt.Println(c.sound())
}
```

But I feel I'm going about this all wrong.  I know I can put `sound()` in an interface, but then the specific animals are sounders, not really animals.  If `Animal` becomes the interface, I can't share the name and the speak code.  I realize the designers of Go went with interfaces-only and chose not do directly support this classic OO use case the way we would see it done in Ruby, Python, Java, and so on, but I suspect there should be *some* idiom or best practice for simulating this.  What is the preferred way of doing so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I suspect there should be some idiom or best practice for simulating this.

No there isn't.

If something like that does come up (and it doesn't very often in real code, but mostly in translations of Java/Ruby/whatever code): `interface Named { Name() string }` and `interface Sounder { Sound() }` combined to `interface Animal {Named, Sounder}` and pass those animals around.

Again: The "prefered way" is to remodel the solution without inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

I think the confusion may be coming from constructing the instances using [`composite literals`](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals).

These are perfect for creating complex types in single lines, and manage, as the previous link suggests, to cut down on boiler-plate code.

Sometimes however, the code may be simpler and more readable by doing things more explicitly. I find this is sometimes the case when taking advantage of [Embedding](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding).

To quote the previous link:

> > The methods of embedded types come along for free

You *aren't* delegating to the sub-class's `sound` method, but the setting and getting of the "sub-class" `sound` transparently uses the `sound` field of `Animal`

So my preferred way of doing this would be something like:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Animal struct {
    name  string
    sound string
}

type Cow struct {
    Animal
}

type Dog struct {
    Animal
}

func (a *Animal) Speak() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", a.sound)
}

func main() {
    c := new(Cow)
    d := new(Dog)
    c.name, c.sound = "Bessie", "mooo"
    d.name, d.sound = "Sparky", "woof"
    fmt.Println(c.Speak())
    fmt.Println(d.Speak())
}
```

Produces:

> > mooo
> >     woof

[Playgound link](http://play.golang.org/p/kvVfFyK5bf)

EDIT: There's [a quote from Rob Pike](http://talks.golang.org/2012/splash.article#TOC_15.) regarding this subject:

> > Go takes an unusual approach to object-oriented programming, allowing methods on any type, not just classes, but without any form of type-based inheritance like subclassing. This means there is no type hierarchy. This was an intentional design choice. Although type hierarchies have been used to build much successful software, it is our opinion that the model has been overused and that it is worth taking a step back.

Comment: Good answer and +1 for giving the relevant Rob Pike quote.  I am aware the we don't do the exact kind of thing I was asking about (implementation inheritance) in Go, but it seems there should still be a way of capturing business rules like "All cows say mooo."  Your solution is close and may be the preferred Go approach, but if there's any way to tie the animal's type to its sound that would be great to have in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can't attach non-interface methods to an interface. If an animal is to speak they need both a name and a sound. Also you can embed private types and what you've embedded is an implementation detail. Given these insights I think this is what you're after.

```
package farm

type Animal interface {
    Name() string
    Sound() string
}

func Speak(a Animal) string {
    return a.Name() + " says " + a.Sound()
}

type animal struct {
    name string
}

func (a *animal) Name() string {
    return a.name
}

type Cow struct {
    animal
}

func NewCow(name string) *Cow {
    return &Cow{animal{name}}
}

func (c *Cow) Sound() string {
    return "mooo"
}

type Dog struct {
    animal
}

func NewDog(name string) *Dog {
    return &Dog{animal{name}}
}

func (c *Dog) Sound() string {
    return "woof"
}
```

with a main like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "farm"

func main() {
    c := farm.NewCow("Betsy")
    d := farm.NewDog("Sparky")
    //"In classic OOO you'd write c.Speak()"
    fmt.Println(farm.Speak(c))
    fmt.Println(farm.Speak(d))
}
```

Play link w/ main: http://play.golang.org/p/YXX6opX8Cy

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Sounder interface {
    Sound() string
}

type Animal struct {
    Name    string
    Sounder Sounder
}

func (a *Animal) Speak() {
    fmt.Printf("%s says %s.\n", a.Name, a.Sounder.Sound())
}

type StringSounder string

func (f StringSounder) Sound() string {
    return string(f)
}


func main() {
    d := &Animal{"Sparky", StringSounder("woof")}
    c := &Animal{"Bessie", StringSounder("mooo")}

    d.Speak()
    c.Speak()
}
```